# Can not submit data to mysql database with php via bizstrap form

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to develop a database driven app for my bosses company website which is using bizstrap 1.3 template and encountered a problem.

I press to the submit button but no data gets recorded to my database. I couldnt figure out what's wrong, please help me out and point me in the right direction, thanks in advance.

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Kayıt</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/login.css">
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span4 offset4">
                    <div class="signup">
                        <div id="logo">
                            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Bizstrap Logo">
                        </div>

                        <div class="tab-content">
                             <div id="signup" class="tab-pane active">

                        <?php

                    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
                    {
                      $name = $_POST['name'];
                      $surname = $_POST['surname'];
                      $uname = $_POST['username'];
                      $email = $_POST['email'];
                      $pass = $_POST['pass'];
                      $checkpass = $_POST['checkpass'];

                      $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'DB_uname', 'pass', 'companyDB');
                      if(!$dbc)
                      {
                        exit("no connection");
                      } 
                      else
                      {
                      $query  = "INSERT INTO kimlik(ad, soyad, kullanıcı_adı, email, şifre) VALUES('$name', '$surname', '$uname', '$email', '$pass')";

                      mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

                      echo '<p>registration is complete.</p>';

                      $ad = "" ;
                      $soyad = "" ;
                      $k_adı = "" ;
                      $email = "" ;
                      $şifre = "" ;
                      $şifret = "" ;
                      }
                    }

                    ?>

                            <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

                                <div class="control-group">

                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <div class="input-prepend">
                                            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                                            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name" required="required">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <div class="input-prepend">    
                                            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                                            <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" placeholder="surname" required="required">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <div class="input-prepend">    
                                            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                                            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username" required="required">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <div class="input-prepend">    
                                            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
                                            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="mail@domain.com" required="required">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <div class="input-prepend">    
                                            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
                                            <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="pass" required="required">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <div class="input-prepend">    
                                            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
                                            <input type="password" id="checkpass" name="checkpass" placeholder="checkpass" required="required">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <input class="btn btn-inverse btn-block" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
                            </form>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <ul class="inline">
                        <li><a class="muted" href="login.php">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a class="muted" href="forgot.php">Forgot Password</a></li>
                        <li><a class="muted" href="#">Signup</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="assets/js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>        </div>      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: $_POST in allcaps not $_post

Comment: thanks @saadzer but still no luck.

Comment: thanks for your comment @CBroe but your answer is a bit vague. do you mean that the error is in my insert query and i should use something like ,or die(mysql_error($var))? 
i really didnt understand if your intention is to help me or to look smart.

Comment: i guess i did that @CBroe. given error is: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@hotmail.com, 2014-03-15, evosan, 19032003)' at line 1'

Comment: And what does `$query` contain exactly? And btw., using characters outside “normal” ASCII for column names is not a good idea in general. English is _the_ language for programming – if you _have_ to use column names in your own language, you might have to quote them properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
"<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

use
   first of all you should save file name as register.php
 and pass it in form  like

```
<form action="register.php">
```

Comment: thanks for your comment but the reason that this form is self referencing is to prevent the loss of form data that user submits in case something goes wrong, so that (s)he wont have to re-enter every field. (i.e. photo uploaded by user is exceeded max file size.) pardon my lack of xp on the field and please do tell me if I am missing an angle. @VijayBarbhaya